# Why debug mode file size is large than release mode?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, release

I really got confused why the file size (.exe Extension file) of debug mode is larger than release mode when building a application in Visual Studio.

What happens if I publish the files in Debug Mode rather than release mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, I'd like to say that you shouldn't use debug builds for releasing.
The debug executables' large size is caused by lots of additional info stored in your exe file - info about methods and classes, what makes it easier for debugger to use it.
For example, if you publish debug executable, after an exception user may be prompted to close program or to debug it. And, of course, Release Mode executables have all the data required to work at the end-user machine and using them will drastically decrease storage size used by your program.